# Irregular System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Invalid argument issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable, oledbdataadapter

On production system we are **SOMETIMES** getting below  error message while reading excel into datatable (same code same file will not work today but will on other day) .

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Invalid argument.
>         System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable)

But the problem is that on production server it work well today but tomorrow or day after tomorrow it will not work well and then again it will start working well.

Below is the code.

```
     string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + readFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\""; 
     ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString); 
     string ExcelQuery = "Select FORMAT(SAMPDATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') as SAMPDATE,FORMAT(LANDED_ON,'dd/MM/yyyy') as LANDED_ON,FORMAT(RECDATE,'dd/MM/yyyy') as RECDATE,* from [Sheet1$]";

     ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(ExcelQuery, ExcelConnection); 

     ExcelConnection.Open(); 

     ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand); 

     ExcelAdapter.Fill(dtbExcelData); 

     ExcelConnection.Close();
```

I have also checked value of variable readFilePath it is correct , example value is D:\Cop\Web\ABC\PAL\FIleUploaded\ER01.xls.

I am not sure why exactly same code does not allow same excel document to get uploaded but next day same code same file works without any problem. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: It must be your data (spreadsheet). Have you debugged against ones that work and ones that don't.

Comment: @Crowcoder..If it is related with data then how next day same excel file gets uploaded since it gets uploaded without any problem. But thanks I will again check it and will share the findings with you. Thanks

Comment: Same exact file? Same data? Why would you import same exact data more than once?

Comment: do you know if an excel processus get started in the background when using this code? because it might fail because excel process fail to start

Comment: @Crowcoder..Actually if files fails today then we again try to upload it next fews days. That is when we came to know about this irregularity.

Comment: @FranckNgako..thanks for your comment..No in the background no excel process is running.actually we do not have MS Office on production server , that why we are not using interop option.

Comment: ok. well i'm not sure, and don't ask me why. but everytime you are using interops dll on servers, you might want to create a directory called `Desktop` in the location `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\` and let me know in a couple of days if that solved your problem

Comment: @FranckNgako... I am not using interop on server..so may not be applicable for my case, but in that case this issue will come everytime and not sometime.

Comment: I see. I still don't think it has anything to do with the code you have shown. Maybe try ClosedXml to read the sheet data instead and see how that goes.

Comment: @Crowcoder..You are correct , I also do not think that it has to do with code. But rather something on server, like other running processes, datetime etc. I am trying to find those factors on server which may cause this problem.

Comment: well, the day it fails, try to clear the file (remove lot of lines) and give it a try to see if it still crashes. But in your stackTrace exception you can see ExecuteReader is been called which for me means there is a data which is not well formatted. How comes the day after it's all ok, i can't tell. But as you are manipulating dates in your query, it smells the language issue

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions.

1. I *suspect* the issue is that there are rogue instances of Excel/Access (not sure which one is leveraged here) that are preventing the process from working as expected.  I would run a process once a day (or night) to just go in and terminate any lingering client.  We have Excel jobs that run daily, and invariably there are always leftover instances running, causing problems, and you can't even see them running unless you go to task manager on the "Processes" tab.

If you run something as simple as this, it will purge any open instance, even those you can't see:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

2. @Crowcoder gave the excellent suggestion of using ClosedXml.  This, or a litany of other third party readers can read Excel files without the use of OLE, and with no dependencies beyond the .NET framework itself.

It will mean more work on your end to read the contents and turn it into a datatable, but it also creates an opportunity to skip the datatable all together, which might make sense, depending on what you are trying to do.

3. Your comments indicate that the issue is not with the spreadsheet content itself, but I can't help but be somewhat suspicious...  after all, it's a spreadsheet.  There is no such thing as strong datatyping on a spreadsheet.  OLE may make an assessment that a column is a certain datatype only to find a cell that has nearly all dates has the word "NONE" in one cell.

Two things to try here is first, use a datareader instead of a datatable.  This allows you to not assume anything.

In this example, I **think** column A is a date, but rather than assume anything I render it as a string and use `DateTime.TryParse` to test it.

```
ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(ExcelQuery, ExcelConnection);
OleDbDataReader reader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader();

DateTime orderDate;

while (reader.Read())
{
    string colA = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    if (DateTime.TryParse(colA, out orderDate))
    {
        // do something with orderDate here
    }
}

reader.Close();
```

Honestly, I'm not sure if this will work, but it might be worth a shot if you are not 1,000% sure it's not a content issue.

Clearly, this is a lot more work than just slamming the contents into a datatable, but to be honest I've never been a fan of datatables anyway.

4. My final suggestion -- maybe use Interop to export the file as a CSV and load it that way.  It's not a great suggestion, as you are creating an Excel dependency, which may be part of the problem in the first place.